# Azure - Static HTML/CSS/JS as Virtual directories in Web apps

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

im migrating my entire old project setup to Azure, but i cant get my static file content to load.

I got a repository with a folder structure like this:

```
/2015/ <- Static HTML (index.html)
/2016/ <- Static HTML (index.html)
/2017/ <- MVC app
```

The project is setup against my github account, so it deploys whenever something is comitted.

This makes the MVC app get deployed to `site\wwwroot` and my appSettings currently points the root `/` of the application towards `site\wwwroot`. 
I also want to be able to "hit the archives" of old sites, so that if i go to `/2016` - that would then point to the `/2016/` folder of the repository - But i cant get this to work.

I have tried pointing `/2016` to `site/repository/2016` - but when trying to load up the site i get the following error `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Anyone got any idea on how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make these virtual **applications** and not just directories (there is a checkbox in the UI). Otherwise, the requests will still be handled by your MVC application.

In addition, as we discussed in chat, you'll need to move parts of your root web.config under `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` attributes so it doesn't get inherited by the sub app (which can mess it up).

So it can all be made to work, but clearly things are easier if you use separate Azure Web Apps for each :)

Comment: Adding that just brings me a 500 internal server error - :( There is no server side code for these pages.

Comment: Ah yes, that's because of config inheritance. So actually, it really should work with just virtual directory. As a test, did you try with explicit `/index.html` on URL?

Comment: Ah, didnt try that without the "application" checked. It "sort of" works with index.html (its a single page application, so it brings me to a 404 error in our app, but navigating the site after that (even `/`) works, but not at page load tho.

Comment: - So now i just need it to load the index.html as default. Its listed in the default documents list.

Comment: Just to make sure, if you look at network in F12 tools, is it really the request for `/2016/` that is failing with 404, or potentially some of the subsequent requests it makes (e.g. .js/.css files)?

Comment: Only the /2016 fails, nothing else loads.

Comment: Did you also try `/2016/` instead of `/2016`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137850/discussion-between-christer-and-david-ebbo).